# load more button in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax

I have json file in `series.pug` page. When I click load more button want to make a request JSON file and add new element in the page. How can I make load more with using NodeJS or AJAX in pug page ?

```
extends layout
block content
    .content(style='padding-bottom: 100px;')
     #titles
      .container
        .row
         .col-md-12
          .form-group.text-center
           label.col-md-2.text-right Quick Filter
           input.search.col-md-6.text-center(type="text",placeholder='Search series quickly')
        .row.list
         -var count = 0
          each value in data.entries
            -if(value.programType =='series')
             if(count!=18)
              .col-md-3.col-sm-6.col-lg-2.series(data-item-id=++count)
               figure.figure
                a(href='/details/'+value.title)
                 img.figure-img.img-fluid.rounded(src=value.images['Poster Art'].url, alt=value.title)
                 .name.figure-caption.text-center.text-dark=value.title
          .col-lg-12
           a.btn.btn-primary.text-light.load Load More
           script.
            $('.load').click(function(){
                var lastchild = $('.series').last().data('item-id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/request',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data:{'lastchild':lastchild},
                    success: function(response){ 

                    }
                 });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new route that you can make an API call to that returns only partial HTML. So something like this:

`$.ajax('/loadmore?data=jsonFileName&template=pugTemplateName&startIndex=10&load=20')`;

Then in node, you'd have logic listening for this route, and when it comes in, you have node build out your html using your pug template.

So you're query params in this example would be:

```
data = .json file to pull data from
template = .pug file to use as template, should not `extend layout`
startingIndex = starting index for getting data from .json file
load = number items to render html for
```

Finally, you need to use a pug template that does not `extend layout`, so you only get a `<div>` back, and not an entire `<html>` document. In the pug template, pull in the json file, loop through the number of items you want (specified by startingIndex, and load), and then send the result of the pug file back to the browser.

The result of the AJAX call will be partial html, like a `<div>` or `<ul>`, but not an entire `<html>` document. You can then just append it to your webpage where it should be displayed.

Obviously, this is just a rough guide on how to do it, but if you set up the logic like this, you can use this call for any `load-more` functionality you might need on your site. If you post your source code to github, I might be able to give more specifics.